# testing a rails helper that uses cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, helper, testunit

I have a method in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` that calls `cookies`. Which is totally allowed; this method is working wonderfully in my dev environment and knows what I mean when I say `cookies`.

I am testing this helper with TestUnit (in `test/unit/helpers/application_helper_test.rb`) and getting the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `cookies' for nil:NilClass
```

Even for four tests that *do not set cookies*. This has nothing to do with needing to 'set cookies in the test using `cookie_jar`', because the issue isn't that I'm setting cookies and my helper isn't recognizing them, the issue is that **the *object* `cookies` is being called on** is **nil**.

I wasn't sure which controller object `cookies` was being called on, so I `p`'d them all and found that, out of `@controller`, `@request`, and `@response`, only `@response` is nil. So I tried setting it to "cow". And indeed! My error changes:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `cookies' for "cow":String
```

So it seems like I just need to stub out `@response`. How do I do that?

Or am I way out of line here and overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this setup to all of your tests that exercise this method:

```
@response.stubs(:cookies).returns({})
```